# How can I choose between two jars in a different libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, repository

I'm a newbie.

I have two different libraries with the same.jar inside. How can I make the project use one or the other?

```
A 
 |---> test.jar -C:\Users\...\my_local
B
 |--->test.jar - C:\Users\...\.m2\repository
```

Right now, in my pom.xml im using the one in .m2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

What should I add to the pom?

In case you wonder why I want to do this, it is to edit the local library without touching the one I have in the repository.

One of the Libraries, lets say B its the Maven Dependencies, downloaded from a Nexus Repo.

Comment: Can you explain what the first one `test.jar`is? What is `my_local`? Furthermore an artifact is identified by groupId/artifactId/version which mean groupId is more or less equivalent to a directory in `.m2/repository/com/example/test/version/test-1.0.jar`?

Comment: Do you mean that you have two JARs which have the same groupId, artifactId and version?

Comment: @khmarbaise my_local is a folder where the jar is placed.
i dont understand your second question about the groupid, im sorry.

Comment: And yes, I have two JAR's which I assume have the same gropuID, arctifacatId and version. How can I get the groupID of a JAR? @JFabianMeier

Comment: You see the groupId in the POM or by comparing the paths inside the repository. There should never be two JARs with the same groupId, artifactId and version unless something got wrong.

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain myself. 
I've followed the steps from this tutorial:
https://es.wikihow.com/a%C3%B1adir-un-jar-a-un-proyecto-en-eclipse-(java)

Now, I have a test.jar in the Maven Dependencies (the one im using) and installet in a new library, another test.jar. But I dindt give any ID to the local test.jar. 

How can I use the test.jar that is in the local library instead of the test.jar is in the Maven Dependencie.

Comment: The referenced tutorial is ca. from 2008 ... (based on the given Eclipse Ganymed ....) ...

Comment: I would not follow that tutorial. I don't understand the language, but the images show things that should not be done.